# How to move data from GCS to S3 with scheduled jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform

I know that GCP's `Transfer Service for cloud data` allows me to schedule jobs that move data from S3 to GCS.

I would like to do the same but in the other direction.

For example, move all data from a bucket in GCS to a bucket in S3 everyday at 12am.

How do I do this?

(I believe `gsutil` allows me to do it but doesn't allow scheduling and also doesn't leverage spreading the load across multiple nodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Datasync started offering this service recently -> https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/migrating-google-cloud-storage-to-amazon-s3-using-aws-datasync/